# Use colors from other file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How i can use declared colors from Culorii.cs in Form1.cs?

[image]
[Culorii.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYH7q.png)

[image]
[Form1.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6SNG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @NetMage mentioned, you need to make all Members of Culori public. Also you need to create an instance of your Culori class to access the members.

```
var culori = new Culori();
var myColor = culori.DEFAULT_COLOR;
```

Alternatively you could make all members of Culori static:

```
public static Color DEFAULT_COLOR = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");
```

Then you should be able to access it without creating an instance of Colori:

```
var myColor = Culori.DEFAULT_COLOR;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the Culori color members to be `public`. Then

```
Color original_color = Culori.DEFAULT_COLOR;
```

Comment: you mean : public System.Drawing.Color COLOR_DEFAULT = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e5e5e5"); ??????

Comment: Yes that should make the member accessible.

Comment: yea but in codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Culori.COLOR_BLUE_TEXT; don't work

Comment: What error do you get? Did you make `COLOR_BLUE_TEXT` `public`?